# How can I use variables in regular expression objects that are in verbose mode in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have the following regular expression object set up (I have edited it to be a bit more minimal.)

```py
myRegex = re.compile(r'' + re.escape(inputCharacter) + r'')
```

`inputCharacter` refers to a character that the user enters previously. 
For my own benefit, I often prefer to use the verbose mode with my regular expressions, however, after researching, I am still not sure how I can use variables inside a verbose regular expression object (if I can that is.)

For example:

```py
myRegex = re.compile(r'''
    MYVARIABLE
''', re.VERBOSE)
```

When I use the re.escape inside the multi-line regular expression, it gets treated as an item to match.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe `myRegex = re.compile(r'''
    {}
'''.format(MYVARIABLE), re.VERBOSE)`

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer f-strings with this type of commenting:

```py
regex = (
    # Comments
    r"\.[^\.]*"
    # More comments
    rf"{variable1}[]"
)
```

And forget the re.VERBOSE-flag as it makes debugger difficult to use. Personal preference I suppose.